# I have found virus on Ubuntu, what to do?

Tags: webserver, malware

My LAMP server got a virus. (I think.) The root partition started to fill up. But there is no clue as to what it filled up with (no logs). After restart, the used space of the root went back to 4% (as normal). I reinstalled the server, but I saved the old root files to preserve the configuration.

Afterwards, I tried to delete the saved files, it started to disappear only one files I could not delete with root and then something started to build up the whole "old" root file structure again. All the deleted folders came back. I needed to format the drive to get rid of it. Unfortunately I have another copy from this. Do I have to do some kind of security action?

Comment: You should find out **what** fills `/`. [This SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019116/using-ls-to-list-directories-and-their-total-sizes)  may give you help in finding what uses disk space.

Comment: Thanks,  I formated the drive. Of course I do not have backup. How can be Linux system compromised?

Comment: By security hole, or user running code with backdoors. Which is pretty much the same way **all** operating systems can be compromised.

Comment: Hi, I could not locate it with du. It could hows everything with the normal size and could not read some file: {    du: cannot access 'proc/1096/task/1096/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1096/task/1096/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1096/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1096/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory }
As I remember we managed to located these process with the size of 160 TB. Which is strange. We do not have external storage connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe that your system has been compromised,

1. Take your system offline
2. If you intend to do a security analysis, use `dd` to preserve a copy of your compromised system on a separate safe media. I suspect this is what you mean by a 'security action'. You cannot file a useful security bug until you know what the vulnerability is, so keep investigating on your test system.
3. Wipe your disk, and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch
4. Restore your data from backups. DO NOT migrate data from the compromised system

If you don't have backups, then you have just learned an important life lesson.